# warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]

Tags: c++, warnings

very simple code does warn me. Some hints are not constructive. Warning is:

ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]

I tried:

```
char const *q = "pin";
char const *r = "\n\r";
{
while(client.findUntil(*q, *r))
```

without success

Origin code:

```
while(client.findUntil("pin", "\n\r"))
```

Comment: The problem is likely `findUntil` not being declared const correct. Can't know for sure.

Comment: The codes can’t be proper since one gets a literal string and the other a `char` due to dereferencing, so it cannot complain about `char*`

Comment: I was getting this same warning on arduino with char* allNames[5] = {"one","two"...}.
Thanks to comment I altered to const char* allNames[5] = {"one",...} and the warning went away.  Thanks.

Comment: if you can change client method the change it to
    findUntil(const char* p, const char* q)

Answer (score 42):

> ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
>
> ```
> while(client.findUntil("pin", "\n\r"))
> ```

The warning means that your program is ill-formed. You didn't show the declaration, but from context, we can deduce that the argument of `findUntil` is `char*`. You may not pass a string literal to such function.

It used to be well-formed - but deprecated - to pass a string literal as `char*` prior to C++11.

> I tried:
>
> ```
> char const *q = "pin";
> char const *r = "\n\r";
> ```

These are correct by themselves, but

> ```
> while(client.findUntil(*q, *r))
> ```

This makes no sense. Previously your were attempting to pass a string, but now you indirect through the character pointer so you are passing a character. Unless the function is a template, this cannot possibly work.

`findUntil(q, r)` won't work either, because the pointers to const won't implicitly convert to pointers to non-const.

A correct solution is to copy the string literals into modifiable arrays:

```
char q[] = "pin";
char r[] = "\n\r";
{
    while(client.findUntil(q, r))
```

Another is to fix `findUntil` to accept a pointer to const char instead. Then you can use string literals, since they can be converted to a pointer to const char.

Comment: I solved it with following code:
`char* q = (char*)"pin";`
`char* r = (char*)"\n\r";`
`... while(client.findUntil(q,r); ...`

Comment: @realhanno that's slightly dangerous unless you know exactly what the function `findUntil` does, and in particular know that it doesn't modify the strings pointed by the arguments. Fixing `findUntil` to use pointers to const char is better solution.

Comment: Thanks. Function is good. And better...